# How to restrict regular expression to smaller capture

Tags: ruby, regex

Here's my text:

```
"A popular resource for the Christian community in the Asheville area."
"I love the acting community in the Orange County area."
```

I'd like to capture `"Asheville"` and `"Orange County"`. How can I start capturing from the closest `"the"` to `"area"`?

Here's my regex:

```
/the (.+?) area/
```

They capture:

```
"Christian community in the Asheville"
"acting community in the Orange County"
```

Comment: Does this work `/the (?:(?!the).)+? area/`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWQ4aS/1/)

Comment: `/\b(([A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+\b)(?= area)/ ` might be good.

Comment: Interesting question. I couldn't find a satisfying solution with String and Enumerable methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `(?:(?!the).)+?` [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
/the ((?:(?!the).)+?) area/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dnq2Xx/1). It is almost the same as `/the ([^t]*(?:t(?!he)[^t]*)*?) area/`, but [the latter is a bit more efficient](https://regex101.com/r/Ya2XHd/1) since it is an unrolled pattern.

The `(?:(?!the).)+?` matches any 1+ chars (as few as possible) that does not start a `the` character sequence.

To make it safer, add word boundaries to only match whole words:

```
/\bthe ((?:(?!\bthe\b).)+?) area\b/
```

Ruby demo:

```
s = 'I love the acting community in the Orange County area.'
puts s[/the ((?:(?!the).)+?) area/,1]
# => Orange County
```

NOTE: if you expect the match to span across multiple lines, do not forget to add `/m` modifier:

```
/the ((?:(?!the).)+?) area/m
                           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a tempered greedy solution, so that the matching text doesn't contain another `the`. That way it'll always match the last `the`

```
/the (?:(?!the).)+? area/
```

- `(?:(?!the).)+?` represents a tempered greedy dot which matches any character except one that contains the text `the`. This is mentioned using the negative lookahead `(?!the)` which tells it to not match the text `the`. Thus it ensures that the match never contains the text `the`
- This can be further enhanced by using capturing groups to just extract the text between `the` and `area` and so on. Another way would be to make `the` and `area` as lookbehind and lookahead, though will be a bit slower than a capturing group.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWQ4aS/1/)

[Rubular Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/yIkH3dJnbR)

Read more about [tempered greedy solution and when to use it](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=in the)(.*)(?=area)
```

(?<=) : Look behind command
(?=) : Look ahead command, this will exclude the string you type in after the = sign. In this case, 'in the' and 'area' will be excluded from the result.

(.*) is used here which is 'greedy', but you can use (.*?) to match to the next word typed in the look ahead command.